# Xserverで登録したドメインのメールアドレスからamazon sesを利用して送信するメールがDAMRC認証をパスできるようにするには？

Tags: mail, amazon-ses

example.jpというドメインをXserverで登録しています。このドメインを使用したsample@example.jpというメールアドレスからaws sdkを用いてamazon sesを経由して、複数のメールアドレスにメールを送信しています。このメールがDMARC認証をパスする様にしたいのですが、DMARCの設定はXserverかawsのどちらで行えば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

DMARCはDNSにおいてそのドメインのTXTレコードとして記載します。

質問には権威DNSの情報が記載されていませんので「どこ」とは答えられませんが。